# Imagick compositeImage doesn't apply original width and height but smaller

Tags: php, imagick, composite

I'm using Imagick to create jpeg from 2 png images - one background and one over it. But when I composite it, $image is smaller than original. I tried this:

```
$image->scaleimage(
                        $image->getImageWidth() * 1.46,
                        $image->getImageHeight() * 1.47
                     );
```

and $image is almost exact size. If I don't multiply $image original width and height, they are smaller. What it is due to and how to resolve it?

I use the following code:

```
$image = new Imagick($_REQUEST['image']);

$image->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE);
$image->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
$image->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));

$image->scaleimage(
                    $image->getImageWidth(),
                    $image->getImageHeight()
                 );

$background = new Imagick($_REQUEST['background']);

$background->compositeImage($image, Imagick::COMPOSITE_ADD,0, 0);

$date = date('YMd'); $name = time().$rand;

$background->writeImage(DOCROOT.'assets/uploads/'.$date.'/'.$name.'.jpg'); 

$image->destroy();
$background->destroy();
```

When I `var_dump($image->getImageWidth())` and `var_dump($image->getImageHeight())` , exact width and height are shown.

**Edited:** This is my original code. Problem is that when 2 images are merged into one image, $image has smaller width and height than its original sizes.

Width  `$image->scaleimage` that I used above, I tried to fix that. I multiplied its width and height width some procent, so that I could achieve original sizes of $image.

But my question is why without scaling $image, it's not preserved its original width and height, but they are smaller after sompositeImages?

```html
$image = new Imagick($_REQUEST['image']);

$image->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE);
$image->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
$image->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));

$background = new Imagick($_REQUEST['background']);
$background->compositeImage($image, imagick::COMPOSITE_ADD, 20, 10);

$date = date('YMd');$name = time().rand()&10000;
$background->writeImage(DOCROOT.'assets/uploads/'.$date.'/'.$name.'.jpg'); 

$image->destroy();
$background->destroy();
```

Background image:
[image]

Image is:
[image]

When I place image over background like that:
[image]

Imagick composites it like that - Dog is smaller.
[image]

Image is smaller that its own original sizes.

Comment: I cannot understand what you are asking. Please can you post your original code that shows your problem? If the above is the original code, please can you explain what you think "$image->scaleimage(...)" is meant to be doing? It looks like it's doing nothing, as it's passing the current image size into an image....

Comment: Problem is that when $background and $image are merged, $image has smaller width and height than original. I want to preserve its original width and height. I don't know why it becomes smaller when I composite it. What is this due to?

Comment: Please either i) post your original code that shows your problem or ii) explain what you think "$image->scaleimage(...)" is meant to be doing.

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost certainly doing exactly what you told it to do.

The output image is going to have the same size as the `$background` image....because that's the image that you're compositing the other image into.

If you want the image that is being composited on top to be the same size as the background image, then scale it to be the size of the background image.

```
$image->scaleImage(
    $background->getImageWidth(),
    $background->getImageHeight()
);
```

Instead of scaling it to be the same size it already is....

> Image is smaller that its own original sizes.

The composited image is not smaller. You are compositing a small image into a large image. In your web-browser the composited image is then being scaled down to be displayed because it is too large to display in place. This makes the image that has been composited in *appear* smaller, but it is not actually smaller.

If you don't want the composited image (including the image that you are compositing into the background) to be scaled down, you ought to make sure it fits into the element on the webpage where you are trying to display.

Alternatively you could try to scale up the image that you are compositing onto the background image .....by however much is appropriate.....however I can't tell you how much it should scale by, that is your own decision as to what the 'correct' size is.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain good. I want image that is being composited on top to be the same size as itself. Now, image is smaller that its sizes. I don't understand why Imagick makes image smaller than it is. I'll update my question and I'll put images you can see what I mean. :)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but I don't think composited image is larger. Image is smaller than background, I've tested this with very small images  and it's the same. When I use scale to make images big, image changes its colors and has blue color in some places.

Comment: That is a different issue - the composite type you are using (COMPOSITE_ADD) does do weird stuff to the colors. You probably want COMPOSITE_ATOP or other more normal operation.

Comment: Thanks. I went back using GD. I just multiplied sizes width some procent. Is Imagick better than GD? There are many functions and predefined constants and I can't find proper combimantions.  I need to rotate $image too.